# How to move a github repository to a folder under a new repository

Tags: git, github

I have a repository named `username/repository1`.I realized that I will be creating multiple projects of same domain so I want to move this repository to a new folder under a new repository `username/domain`.Do I just create a new folder in my file system and include the projects and push to github or is there a simple way?

Answer (score 0):

So far it doesn't have any conflict with any of current project files, simply move it under the git repository. It will automatically be in the staging area. And once added and committed, you can push to the remote repo.

There is no harm in doing, and it's just the norms